# Utilizar valor de una variable php en js sin que se pueda ver al inspeccionar

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una duda, estoy pasando por medio de controlador una variable `$codigo` el cual es un codigo que se le envia al correo para hacer restablecimiento, después de enviado se redirecciona a la pagina donde se debe ingresar para hacer la validación, y yo iba a hacerlo con JS de la siguiente manera

```
<body class="container">
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col card shadow p-5">
        <br>
        <h1 class="text-center">Codigo de Restablecimiento</h1>                        
        <br>         
        <label class="text-center">Se ha enviado un codigo a su correo para poder restablecer la contraseña</label>
        <br>
        <div class="alert-danger" id="errores"></div>
        <form action="/Jomar/users_control/controller/AdminController.php?action=nueva" onsubmit="return validarCampos()" class="form-group" method="post" name="formCod">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_admin" id="id_admin" value="<?php echo $admin["id_admin"] ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="codigo" id="codigo" value="<?php echo $codigo ?>">
            <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" name="codInser" id="codInser">
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validarCampos(){
    var codigo = document.forms["formCod"]["codigo"].value;
    var codInser = document.forms["formCod"]["codInser"].value;

    var formOk = true;
    var msg = "<ul>";
    console.log("codigo " + codigo + " insertado " + codInser);

    if(codInser == ""){
        msg += "<li> Debe insertar el codigo </li>";
        formOk = false;
    }else if(codigo != codInser){
        msg += "<li> El codigo no es el correcto </li>";
        formOk = false;
    }

    msg += "</ul>";

    if(!formOk){
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML = msg;
    }
    return formOk;
}
```

Me funciona, pero al inspeccionar la pagina, pues deja ver el código cuando lo paso al formulario, entonces sí me ayudaran con una mejor opción se los agradecería, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo, haciendo que se envíe el dato ingresado por ajax al mismo metodo php donde se genera el codigo y comparandolo.

JS Ajax

```
function validarCodigo(codInser){
    var parametros = {                
            "codInser" : codInser
    };
    $.ajax({
            data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
            url:   '/Jomar/users_control/controller/AdminController.php?action=verificarRes', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            type:  'post', //método de envio                
            success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                    if(response === "Listo"){
                        formCod.submit();
                    }else{
                        $("#errores").html(response);                            
                    }

            }
    });
}
```

Y en php hago la validación

```
public function verificarRes(){   
    if(isset($_POST["usuario"])){
        $_SESSION["codigo"] = null;      
        $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
        $correo = $_POST["correo"];

        $admin = Administrador::verificarRes($usuario, $correo);            
        if($admin != null){
            if($_SESSION["codigo"] == null){
                $_SESSION["codigo"] = $this->generarCodigo();
                $this->enviarCorreo($correo, $_SESSION["codigo"]);
            }
            include '../views/administrador/codigoRes.php';
        }else{
            $msg = "Usuario o Correo no coincidentes";
            $this->restablecer($msg);
        }
    }else if(isset($_POST["codInser"])) {
        $codInser = $_POST["codInser"];            
        if($_SESSION["codigo"] != $codInser){
            echo "<li> El codigo es incorrecto </li>";
        }else{
            echo "Listo";
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

Ya que es el mismo metodo que redirecciona a la pagina y valida si el usuario existe, entonce me toca ver por medio de condiciones sí el `$_POST["codInser"]` llega para que pueda hacer la validación, y uso el `$_SESSION["codigo"]` para que no se pierda el valor cada vez que intente entrar de nuevo al metodo y no vuelva a generarlo (No sé sí es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero fue la unica que se me ocurrió) Gracias por la ayuda a todos

Comment: Estas usando la sesión del usuario, el problema sería si el usuario abre el correo en otro navegador u otra pc, en ese caso dependiendo de tu tipo de sesión alli tendrias un problema, verifica ese caso de uso.

Comment: Ah, muchas gracias, de igual manera el correo es solamente para que visualice el codigo, no lo redirecciona a otra pagina, asi que, sea donde sea que haya solicitado el restablecimiento, está obligado a ingresarlo en ese mismo sitio

Answer (score 0):

Podrías desactivar mediante `javascript` la opción de inspeccionar elemento.

Las maneras que existen para **inspeccionar elemento** son las siguientes:

> - Clic derecho del ratón
> - Tecla F12
> - Ctrl + Shift + I
> - Ctrl + Shift + J
> - Ctrl + U

Para poder desactivar estas opciones, haz lo siguiente:

En tu `html` para quitar el menú contextual al pulsar el clic derecho:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

En tu `javascript` puedes implementar este código para inhabilitar los atajos de teclado:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {

    if(event.keyCode == 123) { // Tecla F12
        return false;
    }

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'I'.charCodeAt(0)){ //Ctrl + Shift + I
        return false;
    }

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 'J'.charCodeAt(0)){ // Ctrl + Shift + J
        return false;
    }

    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'U'.charCodeAt(0)){ //Ctrl + U
       return false;
    }
}
```

Espero que pueda servirte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo mucho, hay una cosa que quería resaltar por sí alguien más desea hacer lo mismo, y es que el `oncontextmenu="return false"` quedaría mejor ponerlo en la etiqueta html,ya que sí das click fuera del body, si funciona normal

Comment: @DaxTter77 Buena observación!

Comment: Si te ayudo mi respuesta no olvides votar positivo y marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: Si, me ayudo mucho, solo que descubrí que hay otra forma de abrir el inspeccionar, entonces por eso no la he marcado, muchas gracias

Comment: De que forma se puede hacer?

Comment: Por las opciones del navegador, vas a más herramientas y herramientas del desarrollador, y ahí ya sale

Comment: Cierto... Si encuentro otra manera, la publico.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias, de igual manera, para un usuario normal está bien, así que por el momento lo dejaré así

Answer (score 0):

La mejor opción es que hagas uso de ajax y la validación del código se haga en el lado del servidor con PHP.

Pero si no quieres cambiar mucho, otra manera es que ese código lo encriptes con md5 solo bajo este escenario podrias hacer la validación en el lado del cliente, pero no te recomiendo ya que un hacker facilmente puede modificar el javascript y saltarse esa validación.

Para validar en javascript necesitaras la siguiente librería: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5
Después de importar la librería, necesitaras cambiar esta sección de tu código:

```
}else if(codigo != codInser){
```

Por:

```
}else if(codigo != md5(codInser)){
```

y en el value de tu input agregar: `<?php echo md5($codigo);?>`

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

La funcionalidad para no exponer el código ni la validación sería la siguiente:

- Desde PHP

  - Enviar correo que contiene:

    - La url con el identificador del usuario (Ejm: url?idusuario=99)
    - El código en el texto del correo.
  - Guardar el código generado asociado al id del usuario (Podría ser en base de datos o en cache del servidor).
- Cuando el usuario abre el enlace desde el correo, se redirecciona a la página web de validación.

  - En esta página crear el formulario con:

    - El campo idusuario en una caja de texto oculta.
    - La caja de texto para el código.
- Cuando el usuario le da enviar código para la validación.

  - En PHP verificas si el código ingresado es igual al que tenias guardado en la base de datos.

Espero ayudarte con esto, suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho, tienes algún enlace que me pueda referenciar lo que me dijiste de ajax y php? te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: he querido hacerlo con ajax como me dijiste, pero no sé de qué manera le puedo pasar el `$codigo` que llega de php a js sin que se vea al inspeccionar

Comment: Está muy bueno tu aporte, muchas gracias, probablemente lo use después, ya encontré una forma de hacerlo a como lo tenia, el caso es que desde el correo no redirecciona, sino que solo visualiza el codigo, entonces, debe volver a la pagina para ingresar el codigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Pues si, no creo que haya mucho cambio, solo te queda cambiar la parte de guardar y validar la sesión por la base de datos, pero si funcionalmente tu implementación cumple con los requerimientos, entonces es suficiente. Saludos!

Comment: Yo valido que el usuario y el correo coincidan con el que está en la base de datos, sí coincide, entonces el envía el correo, sino, manda el error, Gracias por toda tu ayuda, saludos!!